# Bash Script executing out of order when Terminal is closed

Tags: python, bash, macos

I have a bash script that invokes a python script in a loop. It is working fine (in-order execution) when I run it normally in the foreground or If I run it in the background using '&' and don't close the terminal window. I am running this in a Mac.
My script looks like below:

```
for file in */List*.bin;do 
  newFile=${file%.bin}.txt 
  ./Prog1 $file > "$newFile"
  wait
  python PyProg.py "$newFile" >> Report.txt
  wait
done
```

Thisis how I run the script:
`(sudo ./Script > log.txt) &`

But if close the terminal and I check with 'top' command from a different terminal, It is only showing 'Prog1' and not python.
I don't know if the python is not being run at all or the system does some out of order execution.
anyway, I cannot see any new line being added in Report.txt.

I tried `disown -h %1` after running this to detach the script from the terminal. But the result is the same.

Comment: It's not executing out of order. If `./Prog1` indeed finishes then Python is probably just failing and writing helpful error messages to its stderr which no longer exists

Comment: Is there any way to know what is happening?

Comment: `sudo bash -x ./Script > log.txt 2>&1`  will show program errors and script trace messages, so you can see what the script is doing and how it's failing

Comment: Why do you need a "wait" ? Normally, the shell will wait for prog1 to finish before proceeding. I

Comment: I put wait just in case. But it's the same with or without wait.

Comment: So I tried running the script in background with nohup. And after sometimes I found this in logs:                                                                                                             
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor.                                                                             Please keep in mind the fact that the bash script works perfectly well when the terminal is running.

Comment: The issue got resolved. I tried ```disown``` and then ```nohup``` to detach the terminal but both gave the above error. Finally, i tried ```screen``` which worked. Seems like a Python bug. Thanks, everyone for the help .